# Hosting multiple netty servers for grpc inside a tomcat server, application redeploy issue

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, netty, grpc

I am developing a microservice application and deploy them in single tomcat server. So I am not using spring boot. I am using just spring.

Let's say we have applications call `master-data` and `common-service` When I deploy them in tomcat I can access them via port `8080`. 
But I wanted them to transfer to grpc communication endpoints. Then I had to install grpc libries and netty for each modules. Now I can access their grpc endpoint in ports `6565` and `7575`.

I used spring bean `@PostConstruct` annotation and separately run the grpc servers in separate ports `(6565 and 7575)`. Now It works fine.

But when I add new changes to `master-data` and redeploy it in tomcat **without shuting down the tomcat**, It will gives me `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`
  and when I run `ps -ef | grep netty` in terminal I could see there are processes still tuning on.

It seems like grpc server is not properly shut down because of *tomcat is not shutting down*.

Can anybody give me a proper solution ?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC Java servers need to be shutdown by invoking their [`shutdown()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/e806e387fe9a45d8d20717ece94696784b824c71/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/Server.java#L93) method. I don't have much (any) knowledge about integrating gRPC Java with Tomcat/Spring, but there's no built-in integration on the gRPC side so you will need to ensure the gRPC servers are receiving a programmatic `shutdown()` signal somehow.

The [grpc-java-contrib repository](https://github.com/salesforce/grpc-java-contrib) contains additional utilities for working with gRPC Java, including with Spring. In particular, it sounds like [GrpcServerHost](https://github.com/salesforce/grpc-java-contrib/tree/cfa5f0ae0d5e4858974119d731170323d420f1de/grpc-spring) might be helpful for managing a server's lifecycle in a Spring environment.